# How can I 'fix' ["request" service is deprecated] in Symfony2 version 2.8?

Tags: symfony, request, deprecated

The profiler in phpStorm is reporting:

> The "request" service is deprecated and will be removed in 3.0. Add a typehint for Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request to your controller parameters to retrieve the request instead.

I thought I was already doing this by following this [suggestion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony2/JHhtI4WJ6kw) by using the following code to get the request and session:

```
    $this->request = $this->get( 'request_stack' )->getCurrentRequest();
    $this->session = $this->request->getSession();
```

Is the warning correct or am I doing this correctly and the warning can be ignored?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

This warning can be ignored unless you are going to upgrade to Symfony 3.0 in a future.

If you want to get rid of it I would suggest to follow this warning's message and inject `Request` object into your actions:

```
public function yourAwesomeAction(Request $request)
{
    $session = $request->getSession();
}
```

Comment: Late comment: What effect does just adding the Request #request to the beginning of the action function parameter list have on the route URL signature?  My javaScript's form action and Ajax calls don't know the request object to pass it in along with the parameters that are currently being passed.  I'm not finding this answer in the Symfony manual nor other postings on this topic.

Answer (score 0):

Use like that;

```
$this->container->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();
```

Comment: Might want to take a look at the framework base controller class.  You might discover that your suggestion does not make a great deal of sense.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this one :

```
$request = $this->get('request_stack')->getCurrentRequest();
```

You may want to read the route name via the request variable, so you can do it as follows :

```
$routeName = $request->get('_route');
```

Thanks